# vim: mapping normal/visual mode movements

Tags: vim

I have functions that move my cursor around in normal mode, for example:

```
function! s:Skip(distance, direction)
    execute "normal! ".string(a:distance).a:direction
endfunction
```

where `a:distance` is an integer and `a:direction` is something like `'h'` or `'l'`.  This works fine as a normal mode mapping, however, I would like to extend these motions into visual mode.

The problem is that an `execute "normal! etc..."` command run while in visual mode doesn't work (i.e. does not perform the cursor movement as if in normal mode selecting the text between the original and final cursor positions).  One work around could be to: exit visual mode, drop a mark, execute `skip()` then visually select from the new cursor position to the mark.  I don't care for this solution not only because it requires a mark, but it also doesn't "feel" like the correct way to convert normal mode movements into visual mode movements.

Any suggestions?  I should point out that I have many functions like `skip()` which perform an `execute "normal! movement..."` so it would be nice to have a general rule, rather than a one time, piece-meal solution (like the marks, if that is the case).  Changing the way I perform the normal mode movements from `execute "normal! etc..."` to something else is perfectly fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Small tip: You don't need `string(a:distance)`; Vim automatically converts the number to a string for you.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you want to achieve when you call the function in visual mode. after calling E.g. `4l`, your cursor move left 4 times, and you want the selection range to be kept? which means the new cursor position is in somewhere "middle" of the selection area? Or you just want to change your visual selection area 4 chars? (depends on your current cursor pos, beginning or ending of the selection area)

Comment: I think I want the latter.  That is, if `skip()` is `execute "normal! 4l"`, then in visual mode it should be equivalent to `4l` (i.e. it moves the cursor 4 characters left so that you have 4 characters selected and leaves the cursor on the 4th character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the current mode into the function (e.g. via an `isVisual` flag); your mappings know the mode, or you can query `mode()` for that. Then, for visual mode, one usually re-selects the current selection with `gv` (as the selection got lost when you triggered your function from the mapping).

```
function! s:Skip(distance, direction, isVisual)
    execute "normal! ".(a:isVisual ? 'gv': '').a:distance.a:direction
endfunction
```

This will leave the (extended) selection after your visual mode mapping. Note that `gv` also restores the cursor to one selection boundary (usually the end); you may need to account for that / switch to the other side (with `o`).

Comment: Perhaps I am not doing this right, but even something like `vmap s execute "normal! gvjj"` is not working for me.

Comment: That would have to be `:vmap s :<C-u>execute "normal! gvjj"<CR>`. You still need to switch to command-line mode; the `<C-u>` removes the automatically added range.

Answer (score 2):

For a "live" example of the approach in @Ingo Karkat's answer, look at matchit.vim (in the macros/ directory of the standard vim distribution):

```
nnoremap <silent> %  :<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',1,'n') <CR>
nnoremap <silent> g% :<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',0,'n') <CR>
vnoremap <silent> %  :<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',1,'v') <CR>m'gv``
vnoremap <silent> g% :<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',0,'v') <CR>m'gv``
onoremap <silent> %  v:<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',1,'o') <CR>
onoremap <silent> g% v:<C-U>call <SID>Match_wrapper('',0,'o') <CR>
```

I used one-letter codes (`n`, `v`, or `o`) to indicate the mode instead of `isVisual`; just a different style.  As in the comments after @Ingo Karkat's answer, `<C-U>` removes the range that is automatically entered when using <kbd>:</kbd> to switch from Visual to Command mode.  Also note that the `:vmap`s use `gv` to restore the Visual selection.